# Can variables be declared and used in Epicor 10 BAQs

Tags: epicorerp

Is there a way to set and use variables in an Epicor Business Activity Query?

I am hoping there is something similar to the SQL functionality:

```
DECLARE @MyCounter int;
```

That I can then have access to in multiple calculated fields.

I'm currently using sub-queries to try and achieve my goal which is sort of working, but its not ideal, and its not at all elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You cat set parameters which apply to the entire query, but other that than everything you can do in BAQ designer it pretty much a row level operation. Subqueries do get around this somewhat and are probably the right way to go in truth. You can even create Table Functions in SQL and join those in if your want, which is pretty sweet.

It appears that you are trying to use an iterator for something, and this gets starts driving you towards Cursorville in the county of SQL, which the BAQ designer, for good reason, is really not equipped to handle. I might be off on this, so if you post a more specific example I can try to help you out.